# Append Text in edittext using speech to text

Tags: android

I have an edittext for which I am using speech to text. I would like to append text in the edittext instead of overwriting. How can I achieve that. Right now it captures a sentence and displays in edittext. Thanks

public void onClick(View v) {

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
             intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);          
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");



             try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                    et_text.setText("");


                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Opps! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


        }



 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_SPEECH: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {


                ArrayList<String> text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);



                et_text.setText(text.get(0));



            }
            break;
        }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `append` method instead of `setText`:

```
et_text.append(text.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you use your code for the first time ,the `EditText`  is empty,then your code executes and set some text after recognizing some speech,on second run you again want to show the text from the speech and want it to be appended to the last text which was set on the `EditText`.Before setting text on the `EditText` using `setText()`,first call `getText()` on the `EditText`,and save it in some `String` variable.Then concatenate the text generated during second run of the code.

```
if(et_text.getText.length()>0)
{
 et_text.setText( et_text.getText().toString() + text.get(0));
} 
else
{
  et_text.setText(text.get(0));
} 
}
```